# monitoring queries on aws postgresql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds

I installed the module pg_stat_statements but I don't think it would allow me to monitor the activity of one particular Client for instance.

I am trying to spy on the SQL generated by one particular web application to evaluate potential performance improvements

Is there something equivalent to SQL Server profiler in Postgresql on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, I can use the setting "log_statement".

```
UPDATE pg_settings 
  SET setting = 'all' 
  WHERE name = 'log_statement';

SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

In a local (Windows) install of postgresql, it affects all sessions AND I can see the statements in the log file.

Under Amazon RDS, I found that this is only affecting my current session AND I can see the statements in the Amazon-RDS log

To some extent, the AWS feature "Performance Insights" achieves almost the same thing.

However, unlike SQL Server Profiler, I have not found a way to target a particular session

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

pg_stat_statements has userid listed; you may use this to segregate the sqls from one user. Hope this helps.